# MYSQL: query doesn't use the index some time

Tags: mysql, sql

Database of test:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET time_zone = '+02:00';
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `idAccount` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAccount`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idAccount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transactions`;
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `idTransactions` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateTransaction` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransactions`),
  KEY `index_dateTransaction` (`dateTransaction`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `transactions` (`idTransactions`, `idUser`, `dateTransaction`) VALUES
(1, 1,  '2012-12-16 15:52:32'),
(2, 1,  '2012-12-20 15:52:37'),
(3, 1,  '2013-02-01 15:52:37'),
(4, 2,  '2013-03-16 15:52:37'),
(5, 2,  '2013-03-18 15:52:37'),
(6, 3,  '2014-04-19 15:52:37'),
(7, 3,  '2014-05-20 15:52:37'),
(8, 4,  '2014-06-21 15:58:46');

INSERT INTO `account` (`idAccount`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Burger & Burger');

INSERT INTO `users` (`idUser`, `idAccount`, `firstName` ) VALUES
(1, 1,  'Roberto'),
(2, 1,  'Alessandro');
```

Depending with the date passed, sometimes MYSQL doesn't use the INDEX.

I know that I need to add / edit INDEX, please, could you please help me to perform this query very well?

This query **doesn't** use the INDEX:

```
SELECT 
    users.firstName,
    ts1.*,
    COUNT(transactions.dateTransaction) AS num_transactions
FROM users
    INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.idUser = users.idUser
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
            users.idUser,
            MIN(transactions.dateTransaction) AS first_transaction,
            MAX(transactions.dateTransaction) AS last_transaction
        FROM transactions
            INNER JOIN users ON transactions.idUser = users.idUser
        WHERE (users.idAccount = 1) 
        GROUP BY users.idUser 
    ) AS ts1 ON users.idUser = ts1.idUser
WHERE 
    transactions.dateTransaction BETWEEN ('2012-01-01') AND ('2013-12-31')
AND users.idAccount = 1
GROUP BY users.idUser
```

EXPLAIN link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/059d8/7/0

This query **use** it:

```
SELECT 
    users.firstName,
    ts1.*,
    COUNT(transactions.dateTransaction) AS num_transactions
FROM users
        INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.idUser = users.idUser
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT 
                users.idUser,
                MIN(transactions.dateTransaction) AS first_transaction,
                MAX(transactions.dateTransaction) AS last_transaction
            FROM transactions
                INNER JOIN users ON transactions.idUser = users.idUser
            WHERE users.idAccount = 1
            GROUP BY users.idUser
        ) AS ts1 ON users.idUser = ts1.idUser
WHERE 
    transactions.dateTransaction BETWEEN ('2012-01-01') AND ('2012-12-31')
AND users.idAccount = 1
GROUP BY users.idUser
```

Change only the year.

But the biggest problem is that in production environment, with ~65.000 rows of transactions, query hangs on over 60 seconds (!)

I created a sqlfiddle, this is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/059d8/1/0

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please add the explain plans for both queries?

Comment: How is your index defined?

Comment: There's a chance that such a large percentage of your records are contained within the first range that MySQL decides that it is faster to do a full table scan.

Comment: is the SQL fiddle faithful to the original ddl? (including indexes) if so, the explain plans are the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, of course :-( it's my mistake. Providing to correct now. Thank you for point it.

Comment: @Sebas yes, is exactly the original ddl, including indexes. Now I copy and paste both the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @ericpap INDEX is in dateTransaction, BTREE (CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `idTransactions` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateTransaction` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransactions`),
  KEY `index_dateTransaction` (`dateTransaction`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;)

Comment: crap, I can't break it. I spent 15 minutes playing with your fiddle trying to break value spread but it seems it doesn't matter. Damn. @BillCarwin, we need you!

Comment: @Sebas sorry, I did not understand what you meaning.... (I'm not English first language).

Comment: BTW, I'm repeating myself. The big issue is that in production environment the query hangs for more than 60 seconds (argh) with 65.000 rows. In about a month my app adds to the transaction table about 10.000 rows... I need to optimize this query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD KEY `bk1_account_user` (idAccount, idUser);

ALTER TABLE `transactions` KEY `bk2_user_datetrans` (idUser, dateTransaction);
```

This allows all the tables to be accessed by covering indexes, and eliminates some of the ALL type tables. See the SQLfiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b11bb/4

Also, consider upgrading to 5.6, to get rid of the "using join buffer".

Comment: Using your INDEXes seems help a lot my poor DB ;-) Running some other heavy test and I'll tell you (and accept an answer!) ASAP. Thank you for time spent!

Comment: @Bill i have also the INDEX on the field dateTransaction. I need to remove it? This is the actual situation:PRIMARY idTransactions
INDEX dateTransaction
INDEX idMemberCard, dateTransaction

Comment: @sineverba, the index on `dateTransaction` may still be useful for other queries. The order of columns in an index matters. You might like to read my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: The query (and visualization of the resultset) now use about 1,33 seconds, first of your hints and solution... abount 90 seconds. Thank you. I would offer you a beer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. I played with the dates, and if the filter is obviously off (using year 2001 for example) mysql uses its CONST tables to compute the query:

`Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`

I suspect there's a strong optimization on the date columns which I guess is interfering with the index calculations. But I'm not sure about this...

Nonetheless, your query can be improved.

Take a look at this one:

```
SELECT 
    users.firstName,
    ts1.*
FROM users
    JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
            users.idUser,
            MIN(transactions.dateTransaction) AS first_transaction,
            MAX(transactions.dateTransaction) AS last_transaction,
            COUNT(transactions.dateTransaction) AS num_transactions
        FROM transactions
            JOIN users ON transactions.idUser = users.idUser AND users.idAccount = 1
        WHERE 
            transactions.dateTransaction BETWEEN ('2011-01-01') AND ('2011-07-31')
        GROUP BY users.idUser
    ) AS ts1 ON users.idUser = ts1.idUser
WHERE 
   users.idAccount = 1
GROUP BY users.idUser;
```

I moved in the subquery the `COUNT` and the `WHERE` clause, so you only have to use the transactions table once. But it means that the meaning of the query changed, you have to check if it is what you want. Now, the count will count only the transactions between these 2 dates while before, it was counting them in general for the given user, regardless of the date. If you don't think it fits your needs, just ignore my change.

From the DDL perspective, I think you can improve it like this:

1. IF and only IF, you have many different user accounts (cardinality of idAccount >20-30), spread more or less equally:

> KEY `index_idAccount` (`idAccount`) on the `user` table.

2.
Change your existing index `index_dateTransaction` to use the idUser too:

> KEY `index_dateTransaction` (`idUser`, `dateTransaction`)

Final result would be as follows:

[image]

Comment: I cannot move COUNT and WHERE in subquery. In this mode if an user has first_transaction on 2014-01-01 and in where there is BETWEEN 2014-02-01 (e.g.), result will be with first_transaction on 2014-02-01 (incorrect). Btw, you and Bill put me in right way. I'm tring with real DB, I'll tell you ASAP. Thank you for the moment and the time spent, I'm waiting to check with real DB first of accept an answer ;)

Comment: Ah, for your #1 point, cardindality ATM is over 100, so I added safely the KEY proposed.

Comment: @sineverba please take in account Bill's suggestion about the index for `(idAccount, idUser)` which seems indeed more appropriate than just `(idAccount)`

Answer (score 0):

You should have indexes on transactions.idUser, users.idUser and transactions.dateTransaction

Comment: Which kind of index? Could you help me? I have a PRIMARY UNIQUE, look at the sqlfiddle. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need the dates of the first and last transaction for each user with account = 1, plus the total number of the user's transactions within a certain period.

This is best done like this:

```
SELECT  u.*,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(dateTransaction)
        FROM    transactions t
        WHERE   t.idUser = u.idUser
        ) minDate,
        (
        SELECT  MAX(dateTransaction)
        FROM    transactions t
        WHERE   t.idUser = u.idUser
        ) maxDate,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    transactions t
        WHERE   t.idUser = u.idUser
                AND t.dateTransaction BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-02-02'
        ) cnt
FROM    users u
WHERE   u.idAccount = 1
```

Create the following indexes:

```
users (idAccount)
transactions (idUser, dateTransaction)
```

I don't include the primary keys into the indexes which I should have done on MyISAM tables, however, you should not use MyISAM unless you have a specific reason for that (which I don't think you have). Change your engine to InnoDB.

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d92e6/3

On a side note, if this query is frequent, you should consider materializing some of its results. If you keep the daily or monthly transaction counts per user in a separate table which would be updated with a trigger, the most costly part of your query, the `COUNT`, would go away, which would improve the query greatly.